# VS2010: debug WCF service invoked asynchronously

Tags: wcf, debugging, asynchronous

I have a WPF client in the same solution as my WCF service: WPF client invokes service asynchronously but breakspoints set in the WCF service implementation are not hit.

WCF service is in a project of type "WCF service library". It has "Start WCF service host when debugging another project in this solution" checked. I notice that indeed WCFServiceHost is bootstrapped hosting my service but no breakpoints are hit.

Do you have any tips on being able to debug this WCF service invoked asynchronously?

Thank you
Bart

Answer (score 2):

Use Visual Studio's "Attach to Process" option, to attach the debugger to the process running the WCF service host rather than to your WPF client. Start your WPF client without debugging (Ctrl-F5) and then press Ctrl-Alt-P and choose the WCF host process.